# Accessing customSD page on a Sonos One device

Tags: sonos

I am trying to develop a custom music service integration for Sonos.
I saw on their website that they mention a `customSD` page that can be accessed on the IP of the Sonos device. My problem is that when I cannot access the IP:1400/customsd.htm page. I double-checked that the IP is correct.

Is there something I'm missing in my setup? I see the allocated IP address in my router for the Sonos device.

Note:

- The device is a Sonos One
- I also tried running nmap on the IP of the device and the output is:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
```

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, I have a couple of devices running S2 that have the same problem, but most work just fine. I have a Play:3 and a Sub that don't work, but another Play:3 and every other device works fine. I get http error 400 from the offending devices.

Comment: The IP(s) are most easily visible in the Sonos App -> Settings -> System -> About My System